# UDF with multiple rows as response pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to apply `splitUtlisation` on each row of `utilisationDataFarme` and pass `startTime` and `endTime` as parameters., as a result `splitUtlisation` will return multiple rows of data hence I want to create a new DataFrame with (Id, Day, Hour, Minute)

```python
def splitUtlisation(onDateTime, offDateTime):
    yield onDateTime
    rule = rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, byminute = 0, bysecond = 0, dtstart=offDateTime)
    for result in rule.between(onDateTime, offDateTime):
      yield result
    yield offDateTime


utilisationDataFarme = (
sc.parallelize([
    (10001, "2017-02-12 12:01:40" , "2017-02-12 12:56:32"),
    (10001, "2017-02-13 12:06:32" , "2017-02-15 16:06:32"),
    (10001, "2017-02-16 21:45:56" , "2017-02-21 21:45:56"),
    (10001, "2017-02-21 22:32:41" , "2017-02-25 00:52:50"),
    ]).toDF(["id",  "startTime" ,  "endTime"])
    .withColumn("startTime", col("startTime").cast("timestamp"))
    .withColumn("endTime", col("endTime").cast("timestamp"))
```

In core Python I did like this

```python
dayList = ['SUN' , 'MON' , 'TUE' , 'WED' , 'THR' , 'FRI' , 'SAT']
    for result in hours_aligned(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=68)):
      print(dayList[datetime.datetime.weekday(result)],  result.hour, 60 if result.minute == 0 else result.minute)
```

Result

```python
THR 21 60
THR 22 60
THR 23 60
FRI 0 60
FRI 1 60
FRI 2 60
FRI 3 60
```

How to create it in pySpark?

I tried to create new Schema and apply

```python
schema = StructType([StructField("Id", StringType(), False), StructField("Day", StringType(), False), StructField("Hour", StringType(), False) , StructField("Minute", StringType(), False)])
udf_splitUtlisation = udf(splitUtlisation, schema)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([],"id" , "Day" , "Hour" , "Minute")
```

Still I could not handle multiple rows as response.

Answer (score 14):

You can use pyspark's `explode` to unpack a single row containing multiple values into multiple rows once you have your **udf** defined correctly.

As far as I know you won't be able to use generators with `yield` as an udf. Instead, you need to return all values at once as an array (see `return_type`) which then can be *exploded* and *expanded*:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, MapType

# input data as given by OP
df = (
    sc.parallelize(
        [
            (10001, "2017-02-12 12:01:40", "2017-02-12 12:56:32"),
            (10001, "2017-02-13 12:06:32", "2017-02-15 16:06:32"),
            (10001, "2017-02-16 21:45:56", "2017-02-21 21:45:56"),
            (10001, "2017-02-21 22:32:41", "2017-02-25 00:52:50"),
        ]
    )
    .toDF(["id", "startTime", "endTime"])
    .withColumn("startTime", col("startTime").cast("timestamp"))
    .withColumn("endTime", col("endTime").cast("timestamp"))
)

return_type = ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType()))


@udf(returnType=return_type)
def your_udf_func(start, end):
    """Insert your function to return whatever you like
    as a list of dictionaries.

    For example, I chose to return hourly values for
    day, hour and minute.

    """

    date_range = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="h")
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "day": date_range.strftime("%a"),
            "hour": date_range.hour,
            "minute": date_range.minute,
        }
    )
    values = df.to_dict("index").values()

    return list(values)

extracted = your_udf_func("startTime", "endTime")
exploded = explode(extracted).alias("exploded")
expanded = [
    col("exploded").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in ["hour", "day", "minute"]
]

result = df.select("id", exploded).select("id", *expanded)
```

And the result is:

```
result.show(5)

+-----+----+---+------+
|   id|hour|day|minute|
+-----+----+---+------+
|10001|  12|Sun|     1|
|10001|  12|Mon|     6|
|10001|  13|Mon|     6|
|10001|  14|Mon|     6|
|10001|  15|Mon|     6|
+-----+----+---+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: `rng = pd.date_range(start.floor('h'), end.floor('h'), freq='h')
 left = pd.Series(rng, index=rng).clip_lower(start)
 right = pd.Series(rng + 1, index=rng).clip_upper(end)
 timeSeries = right - left` I want to use this code to get difference in minutes., However if I use this section Im getting exception. Any changes required?

Comment: @syv I'm sorry but I don't get your point here. Could you please refine your question and the entire code you use?

Comment: @pansen What is `df` in the last line? It is undefined as far as I can understand.

Comment: @pansen could you please supply a complete example? It's not working because df if not defined.

Comment: @AmitKushwaha: The df is taken from the OP example. I also added it to my answer. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @MaximVeksler: The df is taken from the OP example. I also added it to my answer. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @pansen this is on the brink of alien genius style of coding. It was a pleasure reading and deciphering it. You Sir stand for elegance and sophistication like a true gentleman.

Comment: Why can't I just write a custom udf function just like explode function